# How to find if the part of the search string contains in the string?

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

I want to find if the part of the search string contains the words in the string. The below is the one which works but not exactly as I wanted

```
var s = "foo,";
alert(s.indexOf("oo") != -1);
```

but what I wanted is something like finding string contains part of the search string

```
var s = "oo";
alert(s.indexOf("foobar") != -1);
```

How can i do this? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own function for that, something like bellow

```
var s = "oo";

String.prototype.indexInString = function (string) {
    return string.indexOf(this);
}

alert(s.indexInString("foobar") != -1);
```

So here I am defining a new function on String object, which will take an string and return the index of calling string object in parameter String. It is basically reverse of `indexOf`.

Comment: Simply super. Thanks for replying so fast. It works but could you just tell me how this works as I am kind of new to js.

Comment: It is better to avoid native objects extension. But as it is however a good answer I will not _-1_.